# What do I need to do to make multiple images link to there user defined sites (in PHP)

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, onclick, href

Using PHP, what do I need to code in order for all clicks link user defined sites?

In this gallery.php file

https://github.com/JoomShaper/Helix-Joomla/blob/master/helixPlugin/shortcodes/gallery.php

on line 58 I changed: --- php echo ($modal=='yes')? '#modal-' . $key . '':'#'

to:

```
                  --- php echo $item('src')
```

But when I click on the user defined link (in this case its an image) I want the webpage to open up, instead it goes to the image url which is just a pic of the image.

I new to PHP. So I may have used the wrong terminologies.

Comment: Looking at that source code, it looks like `$item` is an array of image data; you don't have a link to the user's website in that array.

Comment: Im using Joomla and I have only put one image(with an imaged attached) on my page to test everything out.  I want to continue to add more images, possibly around 100.  I need it so that the href opens a webpage for all clicks.  I may need an onClick function or something?